# Need clarification on memory usage of a jar

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, java-memory-model

I'm running a jar using this command. Note the memory parameters. (The jar size is 56MB)

```
java -jar -Xms64M -Xmx256M build/libs/account-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

In my Ubuntu System Monitor, the jar memory usage is shown as below.

[image]

When I profile the jar using YourKit, it shows below, which doesn't add up to above memory usage.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: "Total memory use of a process" has always been a topic that's way more complex than most people realize. It basically depends on which part of shared and non-shared memory you cound. In some numbers shared libraries might be included in others not. So the only real answer is: check what *exactly* each of those tools counts in which numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The jar size is not related to the JVM memory usage at all.

A jar can hold classes, interfaces, but potentially also data that are not directly related to java like images, property files, text files, jsons and so on.

Also a jar holding only a single class cannot be compared with its memory usage. Infact the jar uses classes of the jre (String, ArrayList, ...) that are not present in the jar itself but are loaded in the memory.

What you can do examining the memory using a profiler is a check of the usage of the running application. Basically you can answers questions like:

- Is the memory released when it is no more used?
- Is there any sort of cache holding data and never releasing them?
- Is there any object bigger then expected?
- Can I decrease the quantity of memory for this application
- How often is the garbage collector called?
- Can I suggest to use a different kind of garbage collector?

In any case remember that **the disk size of a jar is absolutely not related to the JVM memory usage**

Comment: The question is also about why the YourKit profiling results don't add up to the total memory usage.

Comment: @Davide Lorenzo MARINO Sorry if the jar size confused you. It was supposed to be an extra information. The question is about the difference between the System monitor and the profiler results.